# Connect 4 objects with rigid body constraint?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a simple question. If I have 2 empties connecting two objects each using rigid body constraints, how could I connect both of these empties? Or how would I make 4 objects connect at one point using rigid body constraint?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup with multiple hinges. and I got it all to work properly except there is A LOT of play at the actual pivot points. Like rubber or something. The faster the object moves the more play there is in the joint.

This seems to be a real problem because I have used the exact setup in blender and unity with the same results. I can't find anything anywhere online about this rubbery pivots problem. I've tried making the mass of the objects 0. It had little effect, but it did help. The only thing I can think of is you can't have multiple pivots working on each other.

The way I did it was following this tut.

[step by step description on how to connect two objects with a hinge constraint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53141/step-by-step-description-on-how-to-connect-two-objects-with-a-hinge-constraint)

Again, I think, hinge joints are useless in this case. Sure would be nice if the joints were actually rigid.

Comment: You can use a spring-type constraint to create a hinge (with angle and position limits) with, well, springiness.  Or if you want something approaching actual rigidity, you can use a fixed-type constraint.